# How to stream game with audio over google meet?

Tags: google-meet

How do I share a game, like JackBox Games, over Google Meet?  Audio doesn't seem to work, and I can't "Share a tab" to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (not Linux, unsure about MacOS) you must:

1. Carefully join the meeting specifically to "**Present**" (Not "Join now" or "Use Companion mode")
2. Select share screen AND Enable audio at the bottom of the share dialog.